Managed Metadata issues in library custom power app form
I'm trying to customize a sharepoint library form for creating new document sets. I'm having trouble with the managed metadata columns.
Two managed metadata issues:

in the combo box (both modern and classic) the term set id # follows the term
the combo box only showing a limited number of terms in the set and searching in the combobox does not find additional terms

Re: the first issue, another poster resolved the term set id # showing up by disabling 'allow search' in the datacard values:
SharePoint Managed Metadata column displays with additional characters in PowerApps Edit Form
This does remove the term set id #, however with a longer term set I need the ability to search for the terms.  Even with enabling search again in the datacard properties, it's not actually letting me search for any term in the term set.
Any suggestions on how to resolve both these issues - ability to search ALL terms in the term set and not displaying the term set id #?

